Date range query including empty or null fields?
Hi I have a large data set and I'd like the query to extract based on date range.
But I keep hitting a wall.
I'd like to extract
All clients that have a Start_dt prior to 01/07/2023 and are empty in End_dt
All clients that have a Start_dt prior to 01/07/2023 and have an end_dt prior to 31/12/2023
All clients that have Start_dt between the 01/07/2023 and the 31/12/2023 and have an end_dt  before the 31/12/2023
All clients that have a Start_dt between the 01/07/2023 and the 31/12/2023 and have an empty end date.
Client_Id   Start_dt    End_dt
Client a    1/07/2022   
Client b    19/09/2022  1/07/2023
Client c    25/12/2022  9/09/2023
Client g    1/12/2022   17/12/2022
Client h    2/02/2024   28/02/2024
Client d    1/07/2023   
Client e    23/07/2023  8/09/2023
Client f    5/10/2023   10/10/2023

I expected the details of
Client a
Client b
Client C
Client D
Client E
Client f to extract
But it isn't extracting Clients with an open end date.  I am tying myself in knots advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Suggestion for the future: don't use null for an indefinite end date, use INFINITY. Makes this sort of query easier.

@AndrewLazarus I couldn't disagree more.  NULL was meant for this sort of thing.  Plus, we don't even know the OP's database.

@TimBiegeleisen Please show us a query that works better with NULL as compared to using INFINITY for an unknown (but future) end date.

@OP are you asking for one query here or multiple?  Because if the former, then some of your conditions can be combined.

What system/database are you using?

@TimBiegeleisen I'm open to suggestion for multiple or one. I was utilising Null. I hadn't considered infinity andrew lazarus
